# Intersection pattern of planar drawing of $K_{3n+1}$

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology

On observing that any plane drawing of the complete graph $K_4$ can be categorised into two types:

- one 3-cycle surrounding the other vertex;
- two intersecting edges;

I am interested thus on whether in general, we also have for any plane drawing of $K_{3n+1}$, existence of either

- $n$ "triangles" surrounding the other vertex;

or

- $n-1$ "triangles" surrounding the crossing point of the other two edges.

Here, I would suggest only considering the plane drawings (continuous map $f:\Delta^{3n}\subset
\mathbb R^{3n+1}\to
\mathbb R^2$) satisfying:

- any two vertices do not coincide in $
  \mathbb R^2$;
- any 3-cycle is embedded in $
  \mathbb R^2$.

My greatest curiosity lies in how one should tackle with this problem, other than exhausting oneself with all possible intersecting curves and monitoring all triangles. Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Your initial observation is certainly false (e.g., there are plane drawings in which all the edges cross each other more than once); maybe you mean to restrict to straight-line drawings?

Comment: But also: it is not known what the crossing number of the complete graph is in general (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)#Complete_graphs_and_graph_coloring and https://oeis.org/A000241 ) so probably any nontrivial question about arbitrary drawings of complete graphs is hopeless.

Comment: @JBL I do not mean straight-line drawings since that makes the question a simple geometric one. To make any 3-cycle embedded, an edge can only cross another one with disjoint endings. Such two edges may of course cross each other more than once, but the surrounding triangles may not necessarily be different for these (redundant) crossings. At least in $K_4$, this is the case.

Comment: @JBL thanks for suggesting crossing number. Could you explain more on how to link crossing number with counting overlapping triangles?